# Как ускорить загрузку yandex maps?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

У меня грузит карты около 5 секунд, мне кажется, что так быть не должно. В документации заверяют, что они загружаются всегда асинхронно. Карта у меня на всю высоту и ширину окна, с кластерами. Жду советов, может кто работал над ускорением загрузки яндекс карт.

Comment: На всех устройствах и в разных сетях 5 секунд?

Comment: Десктоп - 50мб/c

Comment: Попробуйте все-таки разные сети и устройства (сегодня не такая проблема), чтобы как то сузить круг поиска. Причин масса

Answer (score 1):

Не приходило в голову использовать промежуточный кэширующий прокси, который будет локально складывать фото?

Comment: Не приходило. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Ну собственно, если требуется активная загрузка с одного конкретного компьютера, то проще поставить на нём локально прокси, какой-нибудь Small Http Server или аналог под любимую операционную систему, заставить конкретный браузер ходить через прокси в инет и выставить срок жизни кэша много и долго. В этом случае закэшируются и сами скрипты и графика.